# Is REST API design be part of HLD or LLD?

Tags: api, rest

For example for TinyURL design, should we start with API that meet requirements and follow the design to do it efficiently?

Or there is no right or wrong order and it depends on use-cases?

Answer (score 0):

HLD covers mainly architecture designs, info about services, the database used for those services, and how communication is happening among the services.

LLD covers API design, schemes design etc.